# Android App from Library project loading two app icons

Tags: android, eclipse

I currently have an Android app that I've built, and my company plans to implement several different iterations of it - essentially the same app, but with modified resources. So, instead of creating entirely separate projects, I've used the core project as a library and created several shell projects for the variant child applications. Here's where I'm confused. When I launch my child app, Eclipse loads onto the device both the library version and the child version, both as fully functioning apps.

this is the manifest for the library:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.alot.rssviewer"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/launcher_96x96"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.alot.rssviewer.activities.AlotRSSMainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >


        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
            android:value="com.alot.rssviewer.activities.AlotRSSSearchResultsActivity" />
    </activity>

    <!-- Search results activity -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.alot.rssviewer.activities.AlotRSSSearchResultsActivity"
        android:parentActivityName="com.alot.rssviewer.activities.AlotRSSMainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.alot.rssviewer.activities.AlotRSSWebViewActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_web_view"
        android:parentActivityName="com.alot.rssviewer.activities.AlotRSSMainActivity" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.alot.rssviewer.activities.AlotRSSFeedSettingsActivity"
        android:parentActivityName="com.alot.rssviewer.activities.AlotRSSMainActivity" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
    <activity android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MraidActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
    <activity android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MraidBrowser" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
    <activity android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MraidVideoPlayerActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"/>  
    <receiver android:name="com.track.conversion.TrackingReceiver" android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

And here is the manifest for my child project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.alot.rssviewer.worldnews"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/launcher_96x96"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.alot.rssviewer.activities.AlotRSSMainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
            android:value="com.alot.rssviewer.activities.AlotRSSSearchResultsActivity" />
    </activity>

    <!-- Search results activity -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.alot.rssviewer.activities.AlotRSSSearchResultsActivity"
        android:parentActivityName="com.alot.rssviewer.activities.AlotRSSMainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.alot.rssviewer.activities.AlotRSSWebViewActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_web_view"
        android:parentActivityName="com.alot.rssviewer.activities.AlotRSSMainActivity" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.alot.rssviewer.activities.AlotRSSFeedSettingsActivity"
        android:parentActivityName="com.alot.rssviewer.activities.AlotRSSMainActivity" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
    <activity android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MraidActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
    <activity android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MraidBrowser" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
    <activity android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MraidVideoPlayerActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"/>  
    <receiver android:name="com.track.conversion.TrackingReceiver" android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>

</manifest>
```

I'm really confused as to what I've done wrong. I've read that you should have all your dependencies synced across both apps and I've also made sure that I only have the Launcher intent in only one activity, but I'm just kind of at a loss.

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Did you mark the first one as a library project in the settings?

Comment: Yup I sure did. It's definitely a library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried removing more or less everything from the Lib manifest? You do not need permissions nor activity declarations in the lib.

Comment: I removed everything except for the manifest tags, but I still seem to be having the same problem.

Comment: Are you certain your lib is set as a lib? Has it ever worked as intended? Tried clean+rebuild in Eclipse as well as removing both Apps from the device before launching again? This sounds really odd ;o

Comment: Gah. I just cleaned the project and it is working just fine now. I hate that some of the most basic functionality of Eclipse, like auto cleaning projects, just doesn't happen. Anyway, that made it work just fine. Thank you so much for your help, and I'll make sure I'm more diligent in the future about not taking for granted that Eclipse does something it's supposed to do.

Comment: Hehe, it happens even the best :) Good luck!